# cmake find_package ignores required exact package version

Tags: cmake

```
Myproject/CMakeLists.txt:
find_package(Foo 2.0 EXACT REQUIRED)

Foo/CMakeLists.txt:
set(Foo_SOVERSION                1)
set(Foo_VERSION ${Foo_SOVERSION}.8)
```

Why does `cmake Myproject` not fail? It only notifies

```
-- Found Foo: /usr/local/lib/libfoo.so (Required is exact version "2.0")
```

and happily proceeds. How to enforce termination if an exact requirement is not met?

Comment: Have you generated a version file? (see [`WRITE_BASIC_PACKAGE_VERSION_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#module:CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

Comment: No, and have found no concise description of that mechanism. From the page you indicated I do not even understand whether `WRITE_BASIC_PACKAGE_VERSION_FILE` needs to added to `Myproject` or to `Foo`.

Comment: You need to add it to Foo

Comment: Which means this solution only works for dependency packages that are under my control?

Comment: CMake doc of command find_package recommends to use Module mode whenever possible. However, the ConfigVersion file written by `WRITE_BASIC_PACKAGE_VERSION_FILE` is only read in Config mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are also writing the `FindFoo.cmake` macro, then you can add to the macro something like following to enforce version checking.

```
if(FOO_FIND_VERSION)
    # Add a version check logic and set FOO_FOUND as true conditionally
else()
    set(FOO_FOUND TRUE)
endif()
```

Refer https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules for more details.